# scrape with lxml and python from web si

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I would like to extract certain data from websites. 
Originally, I was converting to .txt file and then writing some routines in Python to filter/read out the data, which worked for 95% of the data, which is not sufficient. I found that there is a way with lxml, which I tried, but could not succeed. With XPATH I think I mark the correct position, however, I get only empty brackets as result []. If anybody knew how to correct it, would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Peter

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page=requests.get('http://www.finanzen.net/analyse/ING_Group_NV_overweight-JP_Morgan_Chase__Co__529284')
tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
unternehmen=tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[8]/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/br')
#This should fetch the information about unternehmen

print unternehmen
```

Comment: Have you tried iterate with loop through this list,, or your empty brackets []

Comment: The web page in the question does not exist at www.finanzen.net.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the link, sorry for that. Any other recommendation, e.g. other idea for web crawler, etc. would be appreciated.

Comment: Iteration over the element does not help. I think something might be wrong with the xpath, but I have no clue, what it could be.

Comment: e.g. simple requests like the ones below work fine!
    print tree.xpath('//title/text()') # Get page title  
    print tree.xpath('//a/@href') # Get href attribute of all links

Answer (score 0):

That page source code is a mess. Very little `id` attributes and many *anonymous* `<div>`. You could get the nearest element with an `id` attribute, go up to its parent, root of the table that keeps the element you want to extract. Following `xpath` expression worked for me. Give it a try:

```
response.xpath('//a[@id="commentLink"]/ancestor::div[4]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/table/tr/td[1]/text()')[0]
```

It yields:

```
u'ING Group NV'
```

The last `[0]` is because it's hard to parse non-closed `<br>` tags and `td` column retrieves three text elements, so I get only the first one. You will have to adapt it to your needs.